# How to use COUNT and MAX together but groupwise?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I display the project name with the second highest number of employees?

Relation schema, with primary key and foreign key as applicable:

```
Employee(Eid,Ename,Address,city,Doj,salary) Project(Pid,Location,Pname,Mng,Client,Branch)
Works(Eid,Pid)
```

Eid and Pid  in Works are ForeignKey.
eid and pid are primary keys in employee and project respectively

```
select count (*) , pname
from project natural join work
group by pname;
```

But this will only give the count of employees according to the project... Not the maximum number of employees

```
select max as ex1
from (Select count(*) as ex1
      from works
      where PID in ( select distinct pid from works);
```

I am trying this in linux - oracle

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 0):

OK,I think the SQL below would return what you want(The number 2 project's name and employee numbers):

```
select * from 
(
select
    p.pname,
    count(1) as cc
from
    work w
join
    project p on w.pid = p.pid
join
    employee e on w.eid = e.eid
group by
    p.pname
order by cc desc limit 2
) tmp order by cc asc limit 1
```

Comment: No need to join from employee table

Comment: Yep, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(W.Eid) AS TotalEmployees, P.pname 
FROM Works W
     INNER JOIN Project P ON W.Pid = P.Pid   
GROUP BY P.Pid
ORDER BY TotalEmployees desc
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```